# Coordinate system in swift ios is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to position a sprite at a point :

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Koopa_walk_1.png")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.addChild(player)
        print(koopa.get_x())
    }
}
```

But for some reason my sprite appears in more or less the middle of the screen :

[image]

Edit :

This is the original image (260px by 320px) :

[image]

I expected to see the image appear in the top left because it's coordinates are (0, 0)

Comment: learn about anchor points

Comment: So what point are you trying to position things at? What's the size of your player? Most importantly, for the correct position, what should be the origin of the view? You're missing some very important things for any help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coordinate system of SpriteKit is cartesian, with an origin default of the middle of the screen, when using the starting template in Apple's Xcode.

This template sets the origin to the centre of the screen by using an origin setting of (0.5, 0.5)

To have a top left origin, you're going to need set this to (0, 1), and then invert Y values, to negative values.

Comment: Thanks, I set the scene's anchor point to (0, 1) and my character was correctly positioned